# JSON Mapping Exception constructing Map Key of enum from string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm getting a JSON Mapping exception when trying to construct a `HashMap`. The map is keyed on an `enum`

The input looks like this:

```
{"someObject":{"myMap":{"1":"2"}}}
```

Problem is it treats the `"1"` as a `String` and complains that it's not a valid representation as it's not one of the values of the `enum`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In which programming language you are trying to process JSON data?

Comment: I'm using the jackson library in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the actual names of the `enum` values instead of their ordinal values?

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST;
}
```

and

```
{"someObject":{"myMap":{"NORTH":"2"}}}
```